# React TypeScript onClick event?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm quite confused be the onClick event in React & TypeScript. This is example code:

```
const UsernameFindForm: React.FC<IProps> = (props) => {

    const onClick = (e): any => {
        console.log(e);
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <Button onClick={onClick}>Find Partner</Button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

With the code above I am getting the following transpiler error:

> Type '(e: any) => any' is not assignable to type '() => any'.  TS2322

If I'm interpreting the error correctly the type of `onClick` is a function that accepts 0 arguments and returns any type. Naturally, the `onClick` function has an argument that is, of course, the `MouseEvent`.

Comment: Hey -  const onClick = (e: any)  - this is solution.

Comment: nono, I tried that before. As you can see the type of the onClick function does not accept any argument. so (e: any) does not change the error. You can also see in the error message that the transpiler already assumes (e: any)

Comment: Please show us your `Button` implementation.

Comment: you guys were right! The issue was with my implementation of the button component!